# Using jQuery to match a select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created some JavaScript to check if a username is already listed in the options of a "SELECT" box on my form. It works perfectly but I am fairly sure there must be a neater way of doing it by utilising jQuery better. I've tried searching through the jQuery API, Google and StackOverflow and don't seem to be having any luck finding guidance. If anyone can give me some pointers it would be much appreciated.

Here is the working code I'm currently using:

```
// CHECK IF THE USERNAME ALREADY EXISTS
var found     = false;
var users     = document.admin_form.user_list.options;
var num_users = users.length;
if (num_users != 0) {
   var name_in_list;
   var i           = 0;
   var name_chosen = $("[name=user_name]").val().toLowerCase();
   while ((i < num_users) && !found) {
      name_in_list = users[i].text.toLowerCase();
      if (name_chosen == name_in_list) {
         found = true;
      }
      i++;
   }
}
if (found) {
   $("#user_err").text("That USERNAME already exists, try again");
   $("[name=user_name]").val("");
   $("[name=user_name]").focus();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This whole idea is terrible from a security standpoint, so you know. You are essentially giving a list of all usernames to anyone viewing your site. This makes it super trivial to perform a bruteforce attack for passwords along. Please consider implementing this features with ajax instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what the word "ajax" refers to, I'm basically using jQuery/JavaScript to validate the form and when things are okay I use jQuery's ".post" function to send it to a PHP function that inserts it into my database. The page this is in has also involved authenticating an administrator to get into it so security has been considered. In the end though, this is a project for me to learn about these things and I appreciate learning flaws in my methodology.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that this isn't accessible to general users at least. AJAX is what $.post and $.get do. My main concern was that you freely make your entire list of users available for a general login page, which would be terrible. Also, while having this logic in JavaScript isn't the end of the world, you should also be sure that this same logic is duplicated in PHP, because you cannot assume that everyone will have javascript turned on.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get the logic about how users should be interacting with a page...the whole duplicating client-side verification on the server side seems like a lot of double up. I think for this site I'm going to display a message basically saying, "No JavaScript...no use" is there likely to ever come a time when a web developer can assume JS or am I just going to have to buckle?

Comment: Duplicating validation logic does suck, but it'd a good idea. Generally you should NEVER assume that any data coming from the user is the data you expect it to be. Javascript is always optional. Many people keep it turned off to avoid things like popup ads and such. Also people whole use screen readers and such generally don't have javascript. This page is helpful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Degrading_gracefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can traverse the nodes of a select just like any other element.

```
if($('select option[value="some value"]').length>0) return true;
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be an easier way...thanks so much!

Comment: As an addendum to this, is there a way to ignore case when performing this match???

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var users = $('#user_list option').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();

if ($.inArray($("[name=user_name]").val().toLowerCase(), users)) {
   $("#user_err").text("That USERNAME already exists, try again");
   $("[name=user_name]").val('').focus();
}
```

As [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498614/464744) pointed out, you could try a selector (upvote him, not me):

```
if ($('#user_list option[value="' + $("[name=user_name]").val().toLowerCase() + '"]').length > 0){
   $("#user_err").text("That USERNAME already exists, try again");
   $("[name=user_name]").val('').focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, in particular I didn't know I could set the val to blank and give it focus in one go...I have much to learn about jQuery it would seem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Misread earlier, here is updated code:

`if($('#user_list option[value="' + name_chosen + '"]').length) return true;`

Comment: I had figured these minor tweaks were necessary from John's response but thanks for the clarification.